# Junior .NET Developer interview questions (alghoritms)

Tags: .net

1) Given two arrays, A and B.
Array A consists of a sequence (ex. [1,2,3,4,5,6]) and array B consists of a sequence (ex. [2,4,3,1,_, 6]).
Q: Find the missing element in the array B, no more than one pass of iteration. You can use an array A.

2) Given one array (ex. [2,5,4,1,3,6).
Q: Sort this array, no more than one pass of iteration.

I failed :(

Comment: dud plz apply ur logic. i dnt think u got ans for this..

Comment: And what do you expect now? ;-)

Comment: a) You got two questions in one. b) No one will give you an answer if you do not show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I do recommend to read any good book about basic algorithms.

Comment: Do i get the job if i know the answer ? You can figure it out. Just think a little it's text-book sorting alghorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use a frequency table. 
Example:

- create a dictionary
- add all elements from array A in your list, value 0.
- Iterate all elements from array B, dict[B]++
- Element with value 0 is the right one.

2) Iterate the table A once and put the element at the right place in table B.

Comment: 1) That's not a good idea to create a new data structure (dictionary) Just iterate through A and check that B doesn't contain the particular element

Comment: `add all elements from array A in your list, value 0.` isn't that one iteration?

Comment: How to add all you `A` elements to dictionary without iteration ?

Comment: Real answers:
1) Iterate array A and get sum of all elements (SumA).
Iterate array B and get sum of all elements (SumB).
Missing element = SumA - SumB.
2) Very good :)

Comment: If there's only one missing element and all items can only occur once then that's a nice solution :)